# Efficently insert rows + data

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an excel that has tens of thousands of rows. I need to insert data randomly within this excel. Below I have the function I am using now the main concern is the shifting and inserting data. I need a better idea or a method that can do the same as mine but faster.

A good answer will hopefully show a method and comment to explain how it works. So then it can be reused if anyone else needs it.

Here is mine:

```
    private void shiftRows(int from, int numberof)
    {
        from++;
        Range r = oXL.get_Range("A" + from.ToString(), "A" + from.ToString()).EntireRow;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberof; i++)
            r.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    }

    public void inputRowData(string[] data, int rds)
    {
        int bestRow = getRowByRDS_a(rds);
        string[] formatedData = formatOutput(bestRow, data);
        string val = getValueOfCell(bestRow, 6);
        if (val != null)
        {
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length);
            bestRow++;
        }
        else
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length - 1);
        // transform formated data into string[,]
        string[][] splitedData = formatedData.Select(s => s.Split('\t')).ToArray();
        var colCount = splitedData.Max(r => r.Length);
        var excelData = new string[splitedData.Length, colCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitedData.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < splitedData[i].Length; j++)
            {
                excelData[i, j] = splitedData[i][j];
            }
        }
        oSheet.get_Range("A" + bestRow.ToString()).Resize[splitedData.Length, colCount].Value = excelData;
        MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => MainWindow.mainWindow.debugTextBox.AppendText("Done with " + rds + " input!" + Environment.NewLine)));
    }
```

Comment: Maybe worth a try: Read all data from Excel, work with it in your app, then write it all back in one go.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Interop, but the main reason behind bad performance is usually the use of multiple ranges. You should strive to get one relatively big range(if possible the one that represents the whole worksheet) and then execute all the required operations on it, then repeat it with other big range.

Comment: @Raidri I got the usedRange for my sheet ill edit that range in my code now what is the method to replace sheet usedRange with my new one?

Comment: nvm used  oSheet.Cells[oSheet.Rows.Count, oSheet.Columns.Count] = wholeSheet; but still slow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that your `for` loop with the `r.Insert` makes it slow because your `numberof` is large. This causes Excel to shift the whole spreadsheet `numberof` times by inserting one row at a time.

It's probably a lot faster if you insert the required number of rows at once:

```
 private void shiftRows(int from, int numberof)
 {
      // Excel starts at 1
      from = from+1;
      // Insert numberof rows at row from
      oXL.Rows(String.Format("{0}:{1}", from, from+numberof))
      .Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
}
```

Additional questions that can help:

How fast is it exactly and how fast do you want it?
In which situation does it become slow?

Comment: I would recommend to set 'Application.EnableAnimations' to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently write to values to a worksheet, you should not directly write to the worksheet directly.  What you need to do is declare an array of objects for rows or columns only or a 2 dimensional array of objects for a grid.  Populate these objects with the values you want.  Next, declare a Range object from your target worksheet, then set its starting location (Offset) and resize it with the length(/s) of your array.  Write to the range 1 time by setting value of the range with your object array.

```
public static void Write(
        _Worksheet worksheet, object[,] values, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, ExcelFormatter formatter)
    {
        if (worksheet == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (values == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var range = (Range)worksheet.Cells.Item[1, 1];

        // range = range.get_Offset(rowIndex, columnIndex);  // this did not work when cell 1,1 is a merged cell (column wise); offset moves by columns first before rows
        range = range.Offset[rowIndex, 0]; // this partially solves the problem 
        range = range.Offset[0, columnIndex];

        // may need a different algo if cell 1,1 is a merged cell (row wise)
        range = range.Resize[values.GetLength(0), values.GetLength(1)];
        range.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, values);
        if (formatter != null)
        {
            formatter.Invoke(range);
        }

        ReleaseObject(range);
    }
```